# Dynamically add and remove nested form fields

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

[image: The form view]

I've been following along with the out-of-date railscasts:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

I've been trying to make the code work in Rails 3 but unfortunately I have only been able to make the remove function work intermittently (I broke the code elsewhere).

I've also tried playing around with the 'nested_form' gem which seems to work great in a squeaky-clean scaffold-generated environment but doesn't seem to slot into my current project neatly. Furthermore, I really want to understand what's going on behind the scenes rather than get a quick gem-fix on this one as it is a core part of my app.

Any tips on dynamically adding or removing nested fields with JQuery or some decent helper methods would be really, really appreciated.

Comment: Are you going to post any code for people to help you with? We are not psychic jedi's ;)

Answer (score 0):

Could you post any additional issue that you were/are having with the nested_form gem? It took me a bit to get it up and running due to my own incompetence, but it does seem to work for me.

If you are looking for something more explicit code-wise, you could just create a helper method to jQuery clone() the first element in your list, cleanse out any inputs, and jQuery append() it to the end of the list of nested elements.

Answer (score -2):

Ryan Bates made a maintained gem from his screencasts, simply use it: https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

Comment: Hey I've been trying to get nested_gem to work but to no avail... I will keep trying!